# Issue installing zenipy, ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'gi'

Tags: python, module, pycharm, zenity

I'm trying to import zenipy for windows 10 after reading and experiencing that zenity-python simply will not work. So I installed zenipy and got the 'successfully installed' message from the command line but now when trying to import it I get :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

in PyCharm I am writing:

```
from zenipy import *
```

Please can someone help me to import zenipy and tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Please check that `zenipy` is installed on Python configured in `File - Settings - Project - Project Interpreter`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not installed or don't have the dependencies that need. Try `pip uninstall zenipy` and then `pip install zenipy`.

Or download and install the repo on GitHub.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/poulp/zenipy.git
$ cd ./zenipy
$ python setup.py install
```